# How to get a domain specific cookie when there's multiple cookies with the same name but a different domain?

Tags: c#, cookies

I have 2 domains:

- my.site.com
- develop.my.site.com

I store a cookie on this application. Let's call is `MyCookie`.

When I have my main site open, `MyCookie` is available on domain `my.site.com`. 
When I also have my develop site open, there's another `MyCookie` available on domain `develop.my.site.com`, but also the `MyCookie` on domain `my.site.com`.

Now, on the develop website, when I try to retrieve `MyCookie` from the request (`System.Web.HttpRequestWrapper.Cookies["MyCookie"]`) I would expect to either get 2 cookies, or at least the one with the most specific domain, but I get the cookie-value from `MyCookie` (with domain = `my.site.com`)!

The 2 cookies each hold a different value. When I'm on the develop website I'd like to get the `MyCookie` value belonging to the `develop.my.site.com` domain.

How to I get one cookie by specifying the domain, or how to get both cookies?

Comment: Are you using HTTP `Set-Cookie` with a domain-name? If so, then note that `www.develop.mysite.com` is not a subdomain of `www.mysite.com` hence why cookies aren't shared. If it was `develop.www.mysite.com` then it would be different.

Comment: I updated the question to cause less confusion. The cookies are created by creating a HttpCookie an setting its Domain and adding it to the Response